# How to kill a command run from a script after a period?

Tags: bash, shell-script, process, kill, sleep

I would like to run a never-ending command (such as play a mp3 file in loop)  for a period of length T.

I put the command in a shell script my.sh:

```
#! /bin/bash
vlc /path/to/my.mp3 # will play the file in loop till I terminate it.
```

and then I try to run it

```
my.sh & 
pid="$!" # need to get the pid of the vlc process.
sleep 2.5h
kill $pid
```

It seems that it kills only the process running the shell script, not the process running the command in the script. How can I kill the process running the command in the script?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The command [`timeout`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/timeout.1.html) does that. For example:

```
timeout 10m vlc /path/to/my.mp3
```

will kill it after 10 minutes. See the [man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/timeout.1.html) for more options (for example `-k` to send a kill signal to make sure the program does no longer run).

Answer (score 0):

Love `timeout`

An alternative solution, close to the original post:

my.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
vlc /path/to/my.mp3 & # ADDED & <- will play the file in loop till I terminate it.
pid=$!
sleep 10
kill $pid
```

chmod:

```
chmod +x my.sh
```

Run it:

```
./my.sh &
```